# Using socket.io with nodejs on a server with apache as a reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, socket.io, reverse-proxy

I'm attempting to use Node.js with Socket.IO to faciliate messaging between the browser and client, following [the guide](http://socket.io/#how-to-use).

However, I had to setup Node reverse-proxied behind Apache.  So, instead of example.com:8080 for node, I'm using example.com/nodejs/.

This seems to cause Socket.IO to lose sense of itself.  Here's my node app

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

// this has to be here, otherwise the client tries to 
// send events to example.com/socket.io instead of example.com/nodejs/socket.io
io.set( 'resource', '/nodejs/socket.io' );

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.emit('bar', { one: '1'});

  socket.on('foo', function( data )
  {
    console.log( data );
  });

});
```

And here's what my client file looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Socket.IO test</title>

  <script src="http://example.com/nodejs/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

  <script>

  var socket = io.connect('http://example.com/nodejs/');

  console.log( socket );

  socket.on( 'bar', function (data)
  {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit( 'foo', {bar:'baz'} );
  });

  socket.emit('foo',{bar:'baz'});

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem here is the script reference to http://example.com/nodejs/socket.io/socket.io.js. It doesn't return the expected javasscript content - instead it returns "Welcome to socket.io" as if I hit http://example.com/nodejs/.

Any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: I know this is unrelated to the question at hand (and please call me out if I should open a new SO question), but I am curious as to what your Apache httpd.conf looks like. I have proxying set up for passing off to the actual node.js server, however, I cannot get the websockets proxy working.  Could you please give an example of how you are doing this with Apache?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot. This project was done at a hackathon over 2 years ago and the server that was set up for it no longer exists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This ended up being a multi-pronged solutions.

First, on the server end of things, I had to set up the endpoints like this

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

var rootSockets = io.of('/nodejs').on('connection', function(socket)
{
  // stuff
});

var otherSockets = io.of('nodejs/other').on('connection', function(socket)
{
  // stuff
});
```

Then, on the client-side, to properly connect looks like this

```
var socket = io.connect(
    'http://example.com/nodejs/'
  , {resource: 'nodejs/socket.io'}
);

// The usage of .of() is important
socket.of('/nodejs').on( 'event', function(){} );
socket.of('/nodejs/other').on( 'event', function(){} );
```

After this, it all worked.  Remember, on this server Apache is proxying example.com/nodejs to port 8080 internally.

Comment: Which version of socket.io you used? I tried the solution mentioned. But all the http headers gets removed if the web socket request is routed through apache mod_proxy. So, socket.io closes the connection as "websocket connection invalid".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this has anything to do with your apache proxy, but some 'quirks' with how socket.io handles requests on a sub-directory. See my answer here. [NGINX configuration to work with Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373218/nginx-configuration-to-work-with-socket-io/9373699#9373699)

Basically, you need to use this connect statement instead:

`var socket = io.connect('http://example.com', {resource:'nodejs/socket.io'});`

Comment: As of socket.io 1.0 `{resource: ... ` is replaced by `{path: ... `

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested, only this worked for me.
Replace port 3000 with your Nodejs port

Apache 2.2.14 inside your VirtualHost

```
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
      <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
      </Proxy>
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling
    RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://localhost:3001/$1 [P]

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass /socket.io/ ws://localhost:3001/socket.io/
    ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/ ws://localhost:3001/socket.io/
```

Client side connection:

```
  var myIoSocket = io.connect($location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host(), {path: '/socket.io'});
```

No need to change anything on Node.js side.