# Node.js for chat in a PHP website

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, chat

Is it possible to create a PHP website with chatting capabilities, the chatting capabilities written in Node.js? It's just that all the tutorials I have read, the index page was served by Node.js. I don't want node to do that.

I want Xampp to do that. All I want from Node is to exchange the chat from the browser to the server. Is it possible. And if so then how? I have already asked a similar question I got no helpful answer.

Comment: what's about an iframe including the chat?

Comment: @Zap7, could elaborate it more.

Comment: You need to present code here, not a requirement list and then ask us to build it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to setup Apache as reverse proxy for node.js on a subfolder 
(e.g. if your domain is example.org then example.org/chat/ is forwarded to node.js)

see this:

[Using socket.io with nodejs on a server with apache as a reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440965/using-socket-io-with-nodejs-on-a-server-with-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy)

Answer (score 1):

The easy and quick way to do that is using an iframe containing the chat application.
This way you can, for example, reach your webpage `chat.php` served by apache:

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/chat.php
```

and in `chat.php` you put the iframe with the node.js app:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:8081/chat.html"></iframe>
```

This way apache and node servers can run together on the same machine without any configuration workaround.
Moreover this can be applied even on a production/live environment with two different hosting solutions (for example) for php and node.