# socket.io doesn't work when using sub-directory

Tags: socket.io

I just encountered the problem.
When I used the socket.io at root dir. it worked well.

#### app.js

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

#### index.html

```
var socket = io.connect('http://host.tw:8080/');
socket.emit('remote:request',{});
```

But when I changed my code to:

#### app.js

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

#### index.html

```
var socket = io.connect('http://host.tw:8080/test');
socket.emit('remote:request',{});
```

it didn't work.

Is there any help? thanks.

Comment: I think I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440965/using-socket-io-with-nodejs-on-a-server-with-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy