# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'onClose' of null

Tags: node.js, iis, socket.io, chat

Iam working on node.js chat application, i've hosted the node.js on IIS in windows.
my intention is to include the node.js in Asp.net mvc as explained by [Jon Galloway](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/10/26/using-node-js-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application-with-iisnode.aspx) for performing chatting( text, audio ,video ) in asp.net web application.

my Installation details: 
iisnode.js - iisnode-full-iis7-v0.2.3-x86
node.js - node-v0.8.19-x86
express.js version - 3.1.0
socket.io version -  0.9.13
on windows 7 32 bit system with IIS 8.0 express

I've successfully hosted the node.js on IIS, and run the samples

But when i start coading socket.io i got stuck..

when i start connecting with client browser to server, i got an error at client browser saying
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'onClose' of null  socket.io.js:1771

In my server app iam using socket.io configuration as

```
io.configure(function () {
    io.set('transports', [    
           'xhr-polling'
         , 'jsonp-polling'
      ]);
        io.set("polling duration", 10); 
        if (process.env.IISNODE_VERSION) {
            io.set('resource', 'node/socket.io'); 
        }
    });
```

Is this issue related to versions iam using (express, and socket.io node.js) Or in my coading,   any idea about the issue please help me.

thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's because you didn't set the resource path in the client socket.io configuration.

```
socket = io.connect('http://myurl/node/socket.io', { resource : 'node/socket.io' })
```

Comment: exactly right. the overal documentation is geared at root-level servers. once you move things the documentation is not obvious. at https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO the notes about configuring "resource" say "This should be the same between the client and the server" and points out when configuring the client you don't use the leading '/' and when configuring the server you do.

Comment: For anyone else arriving here from google, also look at the following question for how to properly set the first parameter of io.connect() - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9373699/753129

Comment: what is this `resource` supposed to map to?