# how to secure btford's socket.io with node express?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ssl, express, socket.io

My https implementation works fine, but after using `{secure: true}` in `io.connect`, I'm still getting ERR:CONNECTION REFUSED. I've followed the requisite steps to securing an express app with socket.io server side, so I am reasonable sure this is an error on my part client side. I am self-signing the certificate. From what I have read this *might* have something to do with it. Some of the other answers recommend stud or haproxy -- I want to solve this with a pure node / express implementation, so please limit the answers to node / express / angular / socket.io and do not recommend adding something else to the mix. [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604905/angularjs-chat-app-with-socket-io-over-https) might be close--is it necessary to have two certs if socket.io is sharing ports like I'm doing?

Comment: If you have a self-signed certificate, then I think you will have to manually have the browser trust your cert before it will allow an SSL connection to it.  socket.io runs on webSocket and webSocket connects over HTTP or HTTPs so it will automatically use whatever protocol your web page is connected on already when connecting to the same origin.

Comment: I was promoted to "trust" and I did--https works, but no wss

Comment: Then show us your server-side nodejs code and socket.io code.