# NodeJS Socket.io client not working

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, socket.io

I've been attempting to get `socket.io-client` to work with a `socket.io` localhost server on the port 9000.  Both the client and server are based in NodeJS.

This seems to connect to the server:

```
io = require('socket.io-client')

socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000', {resource : 'node_modules/socket.io'})

socket.on 'connect', ->
    socket.emit 'message', {hello: 'world'}
    return
```

However it gives the following error:

```
      self.transport.onClose();
                 ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'onClose' of null
```

The server appears to register the request properly:

```
GET /node_modules/socket.io/1/?t=1388048751499 200 11ms - 2.81kb
```

Is there a working example of a NodeJS-based client for Socket IO? Links found:

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'onClose' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295672/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-onclose-of-null)

Comment: Where is `self.transport.onClose();` called?

Comment: I believe that is from the socket.io-client module..  It seems to be a pretty stable module.  Not quite sure why it's not working.  I checked the documentation for the constructor, it seems to be not working as well, had to google for that too lol..

Comment: link here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client

Comment: Alternatively, is there a better way / another module that should be checked out?

Comment: This is not a problem with either `socket.io` or `socket.io-client`. Your are most definately doing something wrong. We need more code to be able to figure out what isn't working properly.

Answer (score 2):

What. lol.  The module on NPM is broken. -.-

Guys do a direct pull from Github -.-  This works.

```
npm install git+https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client.git
```

In v1.0, this worked for me (together with the pong example below)

**Server**

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(){ // … });
server.listen(3000);
```

Express running on dev port (for me, 9000), Socket.io running @ port 3000

Ref: http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2012/01/28/testing-socketio-with-mocha-should-and-socketio-client/#trouble-shooting

Comment: That's an issue from like two years ago. The NPM versions work just fine for me (`node@0.10.24`, here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/8c4dc1353f27b109f2b2)).

Comment: Thanks!  I built on your e.g. and incorporated v1.0.